# How to create new dimension with numpy? (using fast operation)

Tags: python, numpy

I want a new numpy array based on x, y. New array I want has x's elements and y's elements.

Here is recurrence formula:

```
new[i,j] = [x[i,j],y[i,j]]
```

So, new array's size is (x(=y).shape, 2)

Example:

```
x = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
y = np.arrange(-3,0).reshape(2,2)
"""
x = array([[0, 1],
           [2, 3]])
y = array([[-3, -2],
           [-1,  0]])
"""
```

Then, I want to create below,

```
array([[[ 0,  -3],
        [ 1,  -2]],

       [[ 2, -1],
        [ 3, 0]]])
```

I tried this using fast operation like this:

```
new = np.array([x,y])
"""
new =
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[-3, -2],
        [-1,  0]]])
"""
```

Of course, I can use loop but actual size of x and y is too big. Therefore, calculation time will be too long. I want to create the array using fast operation because of fast calculation.

Comment: Maybe you want to concatenate? search "numpy.concatenate"

Comment: Thanks reply. I want to concatenate like append in each elements.
I tried to use "np.concatenate" but the result was same to np.array([x,y]) I tried before...

Comment: I can find this solution by myself. `np.array([x.T,y.T]).T`

Comment: Try `np.stack((x,y),axis=2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [4]: x = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
   ...: y = np.arange(-3,1).reshape(2,2)
   ...:
```

`np.array` joins the elements along a new first axis:

```
In [5]: np.array((x,y))
Out[5]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[-3, -2],
        [-1,  0]]])
```

`np.stack` with default axis 0 does the same thing:

```
In [6]: np.stack((x,y))
Out[6]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[-3, -2],
        [-1,  0]]])
```

But we can specify a different new axis:

```
In [7]: np.stack((x,y), axis=2)
Out[7]: 
array([[[ 0, -3],
        [ 1, -2]],

       [[ 2, -1],
        [ 3,  0]]])
```

We can also get there by doing a 3d transpose:
    In [9]: np.array((x,y)).transpose(1,2,0)
    Out[9]: 
    array([[[ 0, -3],
            [ 1, -2]],

```
       [[ 2, -1],
        [ 3,  0]]])
```

Your double transpose is similar except it first `x.transpose(0,1)`, and then ends with `transpose(0,1,2)`.

The required transpose is easier to visualize if the dimensions differ, e.g. (2,3,4) instead of (2,2,2).

`stack` expands the dimensions of the inputs, and does a concatenate.  It's convenient, but not doing anything you can't do directly:

```
np.concatenate((x[...,None],y[...,None]), axis=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I created array I want by `np.stack`. Your `np.stack` method is more understandable than my double transpose method.